# casein - if models that have has_many/belongs_to can sit within the form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am making a new app and I really like casein (https://github.com/russellquinn/casein), saves a lot of time.
I am wondering however, if models that have has_many/belongs_to can sit within the form.

For example, I have made a tours model that has many subtours (similar to posts/comments relationship).
This all works fine in normal rails, but in casein I have two tabs, one saying tours, one subtours, but subtours obviously doesn't work because it can't read the tour id as it goes through.
s it possible to list the subtours in the relevant tour in casein (like I do in the app currently) and go to edit - and if so how?

Struggling to find such in their limited documentation.

Comment: It would really help if you'd show us the minimal code necessary to demonstrate what you're talking about. Just like a picture, code is worth 1,000 words.

Answer (score 0):

apologies for not supplying code - new to all this. 
looking at the documentation and other posts I don't think casein is flexible enough for what I wanted.
I switched to ActiveAdmin which has plenty of documentation and is very flexible.